# iOS app rejected because of in-app purchase

Tags: ios, iphone

My app has been rejected because of in-app purchase. This is the answer from apple from resolution center:

11.11 Details

Your game app includes In-App Purchase products for consumable credits priced over $99.99, Tier 60.

Next Steps

Please revise your app to ensure that a single In-App Purchase product for consumable credits is priced at nothing more than $99.99, Tier 60.

To edit In-App Purchases:

- Log in to iTunes Connect
- Click on “My Apps”
- Select your app
- Select In-App Purchases
- Click on a Reference Name that is in Developer Action Needed status
- Click Edit In-App Purchase Details
- Make changes to the Display Detail
- Click Save
- Once you’ve completed all changes, click the “Submit for Review” button at the top of the App Details page.

Note: When an In-App Purchase is in the "Developer Action Needed" state, you must make some change to it before it can move to Waiting for Review.

But I don't have any purchases in this state. What i should do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple policies